# Callback for Yii2's GridView CheckboxColumn

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have a `GridView` (Yii2) and one of the columns is a boolean type of data. I want to be able to toggle that value and have it saved in my database.

I need a callback for that, but I don't see `CheckboxColumn` having one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't go looking too far. Just use the [`checkboxOptions`-property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html#$checkboxOptions-detail) of your column setup to add a specific `class` to all checkboxes. Then you can use a jQuery event to listen to changes and report them back:

```
$('.checkbox-column').change(function(e) {
   var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
   $.ajax('route/target', {data: {id: $(this).closest('tr').data('key'), checked: checked}});   
});
```

Yii's `GridView` normally renders a `data-key`-attribute for every row (on the `<tr>`) that you can use to identify the actual record to update.

As an alternative: `$('input:checkbox', $('#w0')).change()` could also work, assuming you don't want the extra class and that the `GridView` is your first widget.

Comment: Uuh. This could work, but it certainly seems ugly. I'll open an issue about that on Yii2's github.

Comment: I guess I disagree with you on that point. The framework can't support every possible scenario so some of the things have to be added manually. Besides, I doubt that a solution directly in Yii would yield a less ugly result as the principle will always be the same: capture the event, report via ajax.

Comment: I'm sure a framework shouldn't support every possible scenario, but, imho, a checkbox callback on a editable gridview is not some obscure corner case, but rather a very common thing.

Comment: Guess that depends what sort of sites you write. In the 18 years that I've been doing this professionally I've only needed this 1 time. Not that common for me I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

All the GridView column can have a callback function.  you can set the `value` attribute of the every singole column with result of the  callback function.